# unable to catch a Oracle error in Python exception handling

Tags: python, oracle, exception

I have a python script which runs an SQL command on a given database.

```
def run_sqlplus():
    sqlplus = Popen(["sqlplus", "-S", "/", "as", "sysdba"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
    sqlplus.stdin.write("set head off \nset feedback off \nset linesize 200 \nset colsep '|' \nSELECT OPEN_MODE,DATABASE_ROLE FROM V$DATABASE;")
    DbStatusCheckOut,DbStatusCheckErr = sqlplus.communicate()
    LOGGER.debug("Database Status details are : %s",DbStatusCheckOut)
    return DbStatusCheckOut
```

On some databases the above script throws the following error:

```
2022-03-15 13:13:32,593 DEBUG    [v2.py:71]: Database Status details are : SELECT OPEN_MODE,DATABASE_ROLE FROM V$DATABSE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I tried to modify the code to include `try` and  `except`, but it did not work with any type of exception like: `except Exception`, `except RuntimeError` or `except "ORA-01034"`, i get the same error as stated above.

python version is 2.6
cx_oracle cannot be used.
What is the best way to handle this error?

Comment: Why are you using 14 year old version? update to python 3.10!

Comment: Please explain why your attempt to add `try` and `except` didn't work. Show examples of your attempt and where it went wrong. That will allow us to better help.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to handle this error?

You are running the SQL*Plus program and reading the output on the standard output. There is not a Python exception because all you are getting is text output from SQL*Plus and the program is working as intended. Even if Oracle is outputting errors to the standard output all it is doing is outputting text which, from Python's point of view is the expected and acceptable behaviour.

If you want to get errors from Oracle then do not connect through SQL*Plus, connect using an Oracle driver such as `cx_Oracle`.

If you must do it through SQL*Plus then you will need to parse the string you are receiving on standard output and look for errors in the text being received.

Comment: cx_oracle is not available.
can i check for 
if sqlplus.returncode != 0:
 print('error message')

Comment: @vivek You can install `cx_oracle` and its dependencies. I'm sure you can check if the return code from SQL/Plus is non-zero; however, it is entirely possible that SQL/Plus might report errors from the SQL statements you run (in your case because the database is not available) and then, after outputting those errors to the standard output, exit cleanly because it has done exactly the intended job of being the client application that interfaces between you and the database and reporting errors is part of its intended job. SQL/Plus does not terminate on the first Oracle error it receives.

Comment: With the older Python 2, you'll have to install an older cx_Oracle version too.  The [cx_Oracle Installation Instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-in-python-2) give the syntax: `python -m pip install cx_Oracle==7.3 --upgrade --user`

Comment: sorry,but getting cx_oralce on the oracle server is not controlled by me.So i have to do it without cx_oracle somehow.

Comment: @vivek Then you either need to: 1) parse the text output from SQL*Plus; 2) talk to the person who does control the server and get them to install `cx_Oracle`; or 3) run your program from somewhere you do control, install `cx_Oracle` in that location and connect to the remote server.